# Get elements randomly retrieve from another table B with data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table A of data.table type which contains a set of elements, I would like to add a new mass column to this table, randomly retrieve from another table B.
I would like to do this with the data.table package, but I don't know how to optimze it.

Table A

```
element
----------
silver
chlorine
silver
chlorine
chlorine
chlorine
silver
```

Table B

```
mass    element
------ 
0.3     silver
0.5     silver
1.6     silver
1.2     chlorine
5.3     chlorine
0.1     chlorine
```

Code to build tables:

```
tableA <- data.table(
  element = c("silver","chlorine","silver", "chlorine","chlorine","chlorine","silver")
)

tableB <- data.table(

  mass = c(0.3,0.5,1.6,1.2,5.3,0.1),
  element = c("silver","silver","silver", "chlorine","chlorine","chlorine")
)
```

The volume of data being very important I would like to use on the data.table package

Expected result:

```
    element     mass
-----------------------
    silver      1.6
    chlorine    5.3
    silver      0.3
    chlorine    1.2
    chlorine    1.2
    chlorine    0.1
    silver      1.6
```

This code returns me an error that can't fix, but do you think the approach is good and optimized?

```
tableA[, mass := tableB[sample(mass), on = .(element)]$mass]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way,

```r
set.seed(42)
tableA[tableB[, list(mass = list(mass)), by = element], mass := sapply(i.mass, sample, size = 1), on = .(element)]
tableA
#     element  mass
#      <char> <num>
# 1:   silver   0.3
# 2: chlorine   1.2
# 3:   silver   0.3
# 4: chlorine   5.3
# 5: chlorine   5.3
# 6: chlorine   5.3
# 7:   silver   0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative data.table approach, if you are interested:

```
tableA[, mass:=sample(tableB[element==.BY$element,mass], .N, replace=T), by=element]
```

Output:

```
    element mass
1:   silver  0.3
2: chlorine  1.2
3:   silver  1.6
4: chlorine  5.3
5: chlorine  5.3
6: chlorine  5.3
7:   silver  0.5
```